# White 1996 trek Y22

Tags: mountain-bike

Hi I'm new to mtb and have myself a trek y22 with carbon fibre wheels, my mates laugh because they say it's to old for anything and most certainly won't be able to go DH or do any kind of jumps!!! Could someone,anyone advise how I could prove them wrong! And not at an over the top cost. Thanks

Comment: It isn't so much about the type of kit you're running, but developing your skills in the beginning (and doing so while wearing the appropriate safety equipment - you're going to get hurt starting, so make it hurt less). Look at resources for developing your skills (there are plenty of them on your internet and at bike clubs), and get the bike tuned up and inspected at your LBS to make sure its safe + operating properly. Remember that people were mountain biking even before there were "mountain bikes" and doing things more difficult with less equipment.

Comment: I wouldn't dump money into a bike when starting as well, since you may find you want a different style of bike as you develop a riding style (or a different bike). This bike does seem to be OK to start with, but you may find pumping money in suspension upgrades and what not on this bike may be better off with selling it and getting another bike depending on your intended use.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't go out and DH on this! The Y22 is a single-crown, 4" travel bike made for trail/XC riding. And better yet, it was made for that type of riding in 1996.

Now, yes, you could take that down a DH trail, but don't expect it to perform like a brand new Demo or Session with 8"+ of travel, dual crown forks, reinforced wheels, and modern geometry.

I would use this bike to learn how to ride and build up your basic skills. That means you can do small (2' or less) drops, small tables, and other technical features. From there you can upgrade to a bike that will fit what you want to do.

Again, I'm not liable for anything you do if you take this bike off a huge drop/jump and it snaps in half.

Comment: To be fair, you shouldn't be taking any bike where the modern DH features come into play without some experience (which I think is something you're getting at). Biking is always at your own risk.

Comment: Agreed @Batman, but if you gave that bike to say Aaron Gwin and told him to ride DH, it'd probably still be amazing!

Comment: Again, the ability to take a certain bike on a trail depends highly on the rider. You don't start mountain biking on a trail, and youtube makes it hard to gauge challenges due to ride skill level and camera work and stuff. Ask people in the area who have ridden there - you certainly need to practice a bunch of things before hitting any trail.